# How to loop with a table values when column value is not incremental in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert the value from the table T1 to another table t2 where t1 is truncate and load and any values can come after load. So how to use Loop to insert data into T2. It should happen automatically no manual intervention should required so can't Use table value parameter.

Suppose table1 has column Id

```
Id
---
 4
 7
15
```

I have to insert the data into table 2.

I have used this code:

```
DECLARE @counter INT = (SELECT MIN(CAST(ID AS INT)) FROM Table1);

WHILE @counter <= (SELECT COUNT(CAST(ID AS INT)) FROM Table1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID) 
    VALUES (@Counter)

    SET @counter = (SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE @counter = ID)
END
```

How to set the counter or pick the value from `table1.Id` value can come differently every time?

Please help

Comment: Don't think Looping. SQL is a query language, not a programming language. SQL performs very well at set based operations, but awful at iterative tasks. What are you actually trying to achieve here? What are your expected results?

Comment: Table has other values which coming from the different source and this code has to run in a procedure

Comment: That doesn't tell me *what* you're trying to achieve here. Edit your question and include the expected results you are after

Comment: Why would you loop???  SQL is a set based language.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any further detail, it seems you could simply rewrite your query as the below:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ID)
SELECT ID
FROM Table1;
```

There is no need for a loop (`WHILE`/`CURSOR`) for what you have here. SQL is a Query Language, and excels are set based operations. What SQL isn't good at is iterative ones, and whenever a `CURSOR` or `WHILE` is used, I would suggest it is almost always being misused; this certainly appears to be one of those times. A `WHILE` or `CURSOR`, for a even slightly larger dataset would be significantly slower, probably by 1,000s of times so, than the simple statement above.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There is absolutely no need for loops in this case. It might be a bit unintuitive at first, but it's really important to learn the proper way to do set operations, if you want to improve your SQL skills in the future.

Comment: Or you could join on table 2 using a left join and the check for rows that are missing

Answer (score -2):

Not sure of your logic and its almost always better to use set based solutions but here is a TSQL loop solution. I left out the casting which you may have to use:

```
declare @curid int
declare @previd int
select @curid= min([ID]) from Table1 ;

while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID) VALUES (@curid)
    set @previd=@curid
    select @curid= min([ID]) 
    from Table1 
    where [ID]> @previd;


end
```

Comment: As with the other answer, this just ends up being `INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT ID FROM Table1;` but overly complicated

Comment: This loops through every row (RBAR) without using a cursor. This is what was asked for.

Comment: Just because the OP asked for that, doesn't mean that's what they should get. Using RBAR to `INSERT` every row is as bad as what the acronym implies it is; it's agonisingly slow. The OP clearly doesn't know why it's a bad idea, which is fine, but that doesn't mean we should be helping them continue with their bad design choices. Much like if you're answering a question suffering from injection; you don't leave the injection in there and just answer the question they had; you educate them on why injection is such a **huge** problem.

Comment: You are conflating injection (which is disaster) with potentially bad design. Sometimes row by row is necessary. Look at the number of procs in Master that use  cursors.

Comment: Yes, sometimes RBAR; this is not one of those times. I'm not confusing the 2 mistakes however, I'm simply explaining why we shouldn't be provided an RBAR answer when clearly it can be improved on

Comment: The user has not detailed why he wants to use row by row. The user is new to Stackoverflow. I would not have taken off points for the question and while encouraging the user to use  a set based approach (which has yet to be provided) it is not the end of the world to show how to do it using a loop.

Comment: The reason i haven't posted a set based solution (which would literally be the statement above) because if it really is as simple as my comments suggest, this is simply a duplicate of the 100's of questions "How to Insert data into a table from another in SQL"; which (no offence to the OP) they could have easily searched.

Comment: @Larnu Since the user is declaring which columns to insert into, you can almost assume there are more columns on the table, and that a simple insert into would not work. Sometimes developers are forced to work on systems that were poorly designed, without the option to adjust, and require solutions such as this.

Comment: @CombeeBowlin *"Since the user is declaring which columns to insert into* so change `INSERT INTO Table2` to `INSERT INTO Table2 (ID)`.

Comment: @Larnu We can make assumptions all day if you'd like. I (and I assume Benjamin) prefer to answer the question as asked.

Comment: I'm not sure, these required the downvote though; and why I took to the comments.

Comment: They require a downvote because they are absolutely not necessary. If the user is going to learn the basics of how to code in SQL, it's really important to take the correct approach for such simple tasks. There is absolutely no reason to contemplate loops in SQL unless there is no other way to accomplish your goal. If they are going to write loops for such a basic action, how are they ever going to learn how to perform more advanced set operations?